# Eliminate immediate array values using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm working on project where I have array simmilar to this

```
var sortBp = [ 'height58em', 'width480px', 'width767px', 'width768px', 'width959px' ];
```

I want to eliminate any immediate numbers array & only show higher number between them

for example, from above array `width767px` & `width768px` are immediate numbers array.

I want to eliminate `width767px` & keeping `width768px` as it is higher number.

So final result will be

```
var sortBp = [ 'height58em', 'width480px', 'width768px', 'width959px' ];
```

Is that possible with pure javascript function ??

EDIT :

I have sorted array using follwoing function but I'm not clear how to remove immediate array.

```
  var sortBp = bpArrays.sort(function(a, b) {
                    a = a.replace(/[a-z]/g, '');
                    b = b.replace(/[a-z]/g, '');
                    return a - b;
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like

```
var sortBp = [ 'height58em', 'width480px', 'width767px', 'width768px', 'width959px' ];
var x = [];
var regex = /\d+/;
for(var i = 0; i < sortBp.length; i++){
    var c = sortBp[i], n = sortBp[i + 1];

    if(c && n && c.substring(0, 3) == n.substring(0, 3)){
        var cn = regex.exec(c)[0];
        var nn = regex.exec(n)[0];
        if(cn != nn - 1){
            x.push(c);
        }
    } else {
        x.push(c);
    }
}

console.log(x);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jbqbk/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible. Just sort the array, then iterate through and collect first and last "apperance" of each attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var sortBp = [ 'height58em', 'width480px', 'width767px', 'width768px', 'width959px' ];
var arr=[];
for(var i=0;i<sortBp.length;i++)
{
    num=sortBp[i].replace(/\D/g,'');
    arr.push(num);
}
var newarr=[];
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
    if(arr[i+1] && arr[i]!=arr[i+1]-1)// for sorted array only 
    //or you can use sort method of javascript 
    //From http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort.shtml
    {
        newarr.push(arr[i]);
    }
}
newarr.push(arr[arr.length-1]);// for last Element
console.log(newarr);
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/R75bd/